# How do I make a list of new elements?

Tags: java, list, input, element

I want to make a list of elements create with user input. Can I directly store an element into a list, or do I have to create a reference? I found how to make a list of premade variables, but I want to create te variables with user input.

The goal of my project is to store dataset and recall them at a later moment.
First I  understand the concept of lists. Therefore I don't think its useful to copy my code at this moment.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Database {

    public Database () {

    }

    public static int numberOfSpawnpoints = 0;
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Add a new spawnpoint.\n");

        System.out.println("State the name of this spawnpoint: ");


        Spawnpoints Sp1 = new Spawnpoints(getSpawnName());

        System.out.println("Name: " + Sp1.getSpawnName());
        System.out.println("Location: " + Sp1.getLocation());
        System.out.println("Pokemon: " + Sp1.getPokemon());
        System.out.println("Spawntime: " + Sp1.getSpawntime()); 

        System.out.println("The pokemon is currently spawned: " + Sp1.isSpawned());

        numberOfSpawnpoints++;

    }

    public static String spawnName;

    public static String getSpawnName() {

        spawnName = userInput.next();
        return spawnName;
    }

    public void setSpawnName(String spawnName) {

        Database.spawnName = spawnName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know how to get input from user?

Comment: Yes, I can make an element and define attributes with user input. Now I would like to store this element into a list.

Comment: What do you mean by make an element? It is simple take input and store it in a Arraylist

Comment: In the class spawnpoints I have written code to receive user input. This gets printed out in the database class.

Comment: So where you are returning spawn point you want to store it in a list?

Comment: I want to make a list of 'spawnName' and the print out the attributes of that element.

Comment: I know that spawnName is not an element. But I tried to give a new element (spawn point) a name. So i could store and retrieve that element at a later moment. But I'm not sure I'm doing it right. If a have to take a total different approach please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Database {

public Database () {

}

public static int numberOfSpawnpoints = 0;
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Add a new spawnpoint.\n");

    System.out.println("State the name of this spawnpoint: ");
    ArrayList<Spawnpoints> SPlist = new ArrayList<Spawnpoints>();

    SPlist.add(new Spawnpoints(getSpawnName())); 
    // the above line will create an object of Spawnpoints and store it in  list

    System.out.println("Name: " + SPlist.get[0].getSpawnName());
    System.out.println("Location: " + SPlist.get[0].getLocation());
    System.out.println("Pokemon: " + SPlist.get[0].getPokemon());
    System.out.println("Spawntime: " + SPlist.get[0].getSpawntime()); 

    System.out.println("The pokemon is currently spawned: " + SPlist.get[0].isSpawned());

    numberOfSpawnpoints++;

}

public static String spawnName;

public static String getSpawnName() {

    spawnName = userInput.next();
    return spawnName;
}

public void setSpawnName(String spawnName) {

    Database.spawnName = spawnName;
}

}
```

Comment: This is how you can use list. Add as many as SpawnPoints element to list.

Comment: I want to thank you for your patience Osama, this is exactly what I wanted to learn. Just to be sure do the < > mean that it contains a element? I'm not sure what this kind of syntax represents.

Comment: Type of elements which ArrayList will store.

Comment: ArrayList <Integer> will store int values and so.

Comment: I would like to review this line SPlist.get[0].isSpawned(). First, .get[0] calls on the attribute of the element SPlist. Second, .getSpawnName() calls on the function getSpawnName. I get this error on all the System.out lines "get cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Its gets the element stored at 0th index of arraylist and call the isSpawned method of your SpawnPoints class

Comment: I get this error on all the System.out lines "get cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this code:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

while (!userInput.equals("exit")){
   items.add(userInput.next());
}
```

Comment: I want to check if I understand this line of code. Does the < > mean it uses a string as arguments. Therefore if a spawnpoint isn't named "exit" the spawnpoint is stored in a list.